# In Akka, how do I know when an actor is ready to use after having been registered with actorOf()?

Tags: actor, akka, message-passing

If I create an actor using context().actorOf() in Akka, I get back a valid ActorRef. However, if I do the same but create an ActorRef using actorFor and the path I know that the actor will appear at, I do not reliably get a valid ActorRef back. How can I tell that an actor has been registered successfully?

In the description above, I could simply use the ActorRef returned from actorOf(). However, in my actual case I create an actor that itself registers a child actor and I need to resolve that, so the problem in general is "how can I wait / register to be informed of an actor having been registered at a known path?".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, there's no guarantee that the ActorRef you get back from actorOf is still alive, since the constructor of it could have failed.

Secondly, actorFor might find the actor but it died just after being found and just before you started working with it.

Thirdly, it's normally good practice to structure your application so that dependencies are propagated in a logical fashion, so that there is a natural rendez-vous point between your actors.

Hope any of the above helps,

happy hAkking!

√

Comment: Agreed on the two first points, the actor may never have been there and may have gone away before you got a chance to use it. On the first, I guess that what I'm really looking for is how to properly bootstrap an actor based system. Should I ask() an actor representing a sub system using a Start message to ensure that it and its subsystems in turn are ready?

Comment: Create your system as a graph of Actors. Then you can use a combination of DeathWatch and the system's eventStream to publish alive/death. It would be interesting to have a LifeWatch as well. But the risk is that it will leak memory if the actor never comes alive.

Comment: when using akka.testkit, you send a message to the immediately instantiated actor.. you need a way to know it's ready..

Answer (score 7):

Since Akka 2.2.1 you can use ActorSelection.resolveOne to get an ActorRef from an actor selection:

```
implicit val timeout = Timeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
val selection = system.actorSelection("/user/myActor")
val actor = Await.result(selection.resolveOne(), timeout.duration)
```

From the docs http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.2.1/index.html#akka.actor.ActorSelection

> Resolve the ActorRef matching this selection. The result is returned
>   as a Future that is completed with the ActorRef **if such an actor
>   exists.** It is completed with failure ActorNotFound if no such actor
>   exists or the identification didn't complete within the supplied
>   timeout.
>
> Under the hood it talks to the actor to **verify its existence** and
>   acquire its ActorRef.

Comment: What if you are not using ActorSelection but providing the remote actor as a constructor argument?