# Scala actor: doesn't receive messages

Tags: scala, akka, actor

I'm stuck on a problem like this: I send messages to an actor, but it doesn't receive, specifically, the code:

```
class TestActor extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case _ =>
      println("null")
    case Landau(args) =>
      println("Got a Job" + args)
      sender ! "Done"
  }
}
```

and the sender, through "ask" method:

```
worker.ask(Landau(List("1", "2", "3")))
```

As a result, it doens't print anything, neither "null", any idea?

EDIT:
this is in the main execution:

```
val system = ActorSystem("TestApplication")
val ref = system.actorOf(Props(new TestActor), "test")
```

and I don't know if relevant, but the main object and that code "worker.ask..." are in different packages

Comment: Can you please add your actor creation code? Also, did you get any exceptions? I assume you understand, that within your actor ALL messages will go to `case _ =>` as it is before your `Landau` case. Advice: turn on debug logging in your Akka configuration to see what's happening with your actors. Also, take a look in to the console, maybe you are getting any messages about dead letters?

Comment: How does it even compile? The second case is unreachable code...

Comment: It gives a warning for it, but of course it's a test to see if the actor works. As I said, it doesn't even print what's in _ case, so i wonder about the reachability of the actor at all.. i will post all the code in some hours, i'm using sbt to run and eclipse to debug, the scala sdk 3.0.1

Comment: My guess is that this message is going to deadletter.  How did you get the ActorRef `worker`?  Did you look it up via `actorSelection` or is it the result of a creation via `actorOf`?

Comment: it's created via actorOf, how to get the deadletter message, if any?

Comment: dead letters are logged, turn on your logging

Comment: but building with sbt i have some warning and actually they should be shown, not? i remember that somehow in another project i was getting a dead letter, but it was a critical runtime error

Comment: Verify you imports. `scala.actors.Actor` ignores method `def receive` and expects `def act = ...`. On the otherhand `akka.actor.Actor` uses `def receive`.

Comment: no, imports are from the usual akka.actor .. a question, if i'm running sbt, how to turn on all [debug] advices? i'm trying to put log.debug everywhere but cannot see any result..

Comment: The initialization you use is deprecated, you should use `system.actorOf(Props[TestActor],"test")` instead. At first I thought this might be the problem, but after reading the documentation it should work as you have it as well.

Comment: thank you for pointing it out. Since on Google the first hit for the akka API is the 2.0 i never noticed the new version, and I see that people are anyway using it..

Comment: Yeah, there are very notable differences in the API between the minor versions, so it's best to check which version of the API you are using. Fell in the same trap several times (though it was the other direction for me, I keep getting the snapshot docs on google).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seem to be those two lines:

```
val worker = workerContext.actorFor("akka://TestApplication/user/test")
worker.ask(Landau(List("1", "2", "3")))
```

In the first line, actorFor was deprecated in Akka 2.2, you should use [actorSelection](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2.1/scala/actors.html#Identifying_Actors_via_Actor_Selection) now. Usage for actorSelection is a bit different, as it does not return an ActorRef as actorFor did, but an actorSelection you can use to get the ActorRef. You can do this by sending an Identify message and receiving an ActorIdentity message which contains the ActorRef you want. Or you simply use the resolveOne method of ActorSelection, the few times I used actorSelection, I always used it this way. This returns a Future holding your ActorRef. So your code here should be

```
val workerFuture = context actorSelection("/TestApplication/user/test") resolveOne
val worker = workerFuture = Await.result(actorFuture, 10 seconds)
```

The second problem might be that ask needs a slightly different syntax, as per the [docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2.1/scala/actors.html#Ask__Send-And-Receive-Future):

```
worker ask Landau(List("1", "2", "3"))
```

Give that a try.

Comment: it gives error:
value resolveOne is not a member of akka.actor.ActorSelection ???

Comment: Does it work if you write resolveOne instead of resolveOne()?

Comment: Sorry, no clue why that could be. Hopefully someone can provide an answer in the question you opened for that. There is a possible way to not look up the actor by path, but to simply pass the ActorRef into the sender via the constructor. Not sure if this is an option for you without seeing the rest of the code. If you try that, keep in mind that Props for actors with parametrized constructors look different: `Props(classOf[Worker],"argument")`

Answer (score 0):

Found:
So, it looks like it was fault of the method actorFor, I was using this worker:

```
val worker = workerContext.actorFor("akka://TestApplication/user/test")
```

instead of this:

```
val worker = workerContext.actorOf(Props[TestActor])
```

and now it works. But I'm not sure of this choice, since I should point to that address.

Comment: Using this will result in a new actor. So the actor you create in the code snippet in your question and the actor created here are different. (Try giving this actor the same name "test" and you will see Akka complain). ActorFor is deprecated as of akka 2.2 (which version are you using?) See the docs for the new actorSelection syntax. I don't think you need the "akka:/" prefix for actor lookup. Try it with just "/TestApplication/user/test"

Comment: I'm using 2.2.1, and if I "create" a new actor with actorselection it says to me that ask doesn't belong to it..?

Comment: Thing is, actorSelection does not create an actor, the actor needs to be already running. Also afaik ask is not defined on the ActorRef as tell is, but rather is defined in Patterns, you need to do import `akka.pattern.ask`

Comment: it was already imported, and yes i'm reading from http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/general/addressing.html, moreover i'm dealing with some legacy code so I'm having such problems..

Comment: The other thing about ask is, the docs suggest three possible idioms to use ask, `ask(actorA, Request)`, `actorB ask Request`, `actorC ? Request`. Not sure the usage you have `worker.ask(Request)` will work, my Scala is a bit rusty in the moment, but that's about the last idea I have ;-)

Comment: so, if I use ask(actor, request) it gives  
    found   : akka.actor.ActorSelection
    required: akka.actor.ActorRef
instead, if I use actor.ask(request)
value ask is not a member of akka.actor.ActorSelection
akka.pattern.ask is imported as docs say..

Comment: Yeah, actorSelection does not return the actorRef, but an actor selection object you can use to get an actorRef, by sending and ActorIdentification message. Akka is really easy isn't it? ;-) But, actorSelection also has a resolveOne method, that will return your actor in the most straightforward way. Perhaps its best I summarize the comments in one post with some more examples.

Comment: I'm keep trying with it, now i found a nice answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10549026/in-akka-how-do-i-know-when-an-actor-is-ready-to-use-after-having-been-registere
but now it tells that resolveone doesn't belong to actorselection!!!

Comment: Should I post another question?